# set line between QHBoxlayout

Tags: c++, qt

i want to draw a horizontal and vertical `line` in my form, i used `QVBoxlayout` and `QHBoxLayout` for showing my widget, but i don't know how to draw lines? i tried this :

```
QLine *myline = new QLine(m_progress_part->geometry().bottomLeft(), m_main_page->geometry().bottomRight());
```

but nothing appeared

i want to have this form :
[image: 1]

but my form is like second one :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QLine` is not something that you can draw on the widget - it is simply a two-dimensional vector (geometry).
In order to draw or place something that looks like a line in your GUI, I would do the following:

```
QFrame *line = new QFrame(this);
line->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine); // Horizontal line
line->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
line->setLineWidth(1);

// Now add the line to the layout.
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
[..]
mainLayout->addWidget(line);
```